# Spring boot updating an existing parent and new created child issue

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

recently i am trying to learn how to use rich model to write code. I have `UserProfile` and `Vehicle`, relationship is `UserProfile` many to many `Vehicle`.

What i am trying to do is, create a new vehicle, link to that user, then save both into DB.
But i face the `SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000, Cannot add or update a child row` error. Details at below.

Hope you guys can give me some input what i am doing wrong.

Part of Entity code.

```
public class UserProfile {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userProfile", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Vehicle> createVehicle(String vehiclesNumber, String description, boolean defaultFlag) {
        Vehicle vehicle = Vehicle.assignNewVehicleToUser(this, vehiclesNumber, description, defaultFlag);
        this.vehicles.add(vehicle);
        return this.vehicles;
    }
}
```

```
public class Vehicle {
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_vehicle",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
    )
    private List<UserProfile> userProfile = new ArrayList<>();

public static Vehicle assignNewVehicleToUser(UserProfile userProfile, String vehicleNumber, String description, boolean defaultFlag) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
//        vehicle.setVehicleId(UUID.randomUUID());
        vehicle.setVehicleNumber(vehicleNumber);
        vehicle.setDescription(description);
        vehicle.setDefaultFlag(defaultFlag);
        vehicle.setUserToVehicle(userProfile);

        return vehicle;
    }

    private void setUserToVehicle(UserProfile userProfile) {
        this.userProfile.add(userProfile);
    }
}

Service Code
```

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addVehicle(String vehicleNumber, String description, boolean defaultFlag) {

    UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository
            .findById(UUID.fromString("95f099cd-e678-4bac-92ee-8c0662d3358b"))
            .get();

    userProfile.createVehicle(vehicleNumber, description, defaultFlag);

}
```

```
Error Message
JPA perform the following action in sequence 
 1. SELECT UserProfile 
 2. Insert into Vehicle table
 3. Update Vehicle table
 4. Insert into user_vehicle table ( user_vehicle act as middle man between many-to-many entity)

SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`smartparking`.`user_vehicle`, CONSTRAINT `user_vehicle_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle` (`vehicle_id`))
```

Appreciate your time to read my question. I not sure why this error happen and why there is Save + Update Vehicle shouldn't be save only ?
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, is column mapping issue.

```
public class Vehicle {
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_vehicle",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), //REVERSE THIS 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id") //REVERSE THIS
    )
    private List<UserProfile> userProfile = new ArrayList<>();
```